# dspic 33 - watchdog timer

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

hi
i would like to know if there is a way to implement the watchdog timer
within the microchip's dspic33 without the configuration bits,
but only in the source code itself
thanks
eran

Comment: Lots of ways, but a HW watchdog is better.

Answer (score 5):

The dsPIC33F/PIC24 allows you to enable/disable the watchdog timer in software.

When the `FWDTEN` configuration bit is set (default), the watchdog timer is always enabled. If you wish to control WDT in software, clear the `FWDTEN` config bit and enable watchdog timer as needed by setting the `SWDTEN` bit in `RCON` register.

See paragraph 9.3.1.1 in [33F ref. manual - Section 09. Watchdog Timer and Power-Saving Modes - dsPIC33F/PIC24H FRM](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70196C.pdf) for further information.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP wanted a way to enable/disable WDT in software, which this answer describes.

Comment: Question is: how to implement the watchdog timer by **software** and not how to enable/disable hardware watchdog timer.

Comment: @GJ Please see eran's reply, in which he clarifies the question. Obviously, implementing a watchdog timer in software defeats the purpose.

Comment: OK mizo, this is now different question, he didn't edit the main question, however you are right so +1

Answer (score 0):

One could have a counter tick down towards 0 on a timer interrupt and if == 0, reset the CPU. The main loop/functional code would reset it back to the initial value to say the SW is alive.

Comment: If a different interrupt with the same or higher prio hangs, it will not help.

Comment: Agreed @Marco van de Voort, that's why my comment to the answer stated a hw watchdog is best, but I thought I would answer the question asked.

Comment: No problem. A comment can be meant as an addition just as much as a correction